# Number of sequences $(A_1, A_2, . . . , A_k)$ of subsets of the set $[n]$ satisfying the condition $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_k = \emptyset$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Determine the number of sequences $(A_1, A_2, . . . , A_k)$ of subsets of the set $[n]$ satisfying the condition $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_k = \emptyset$

I think the answer would be:

We put each of $n+1$ elements in a chosen number of subsets $A_i$: from $0$ to $k-1$ as we can't have a situation in which any element belongs to every subset $A_i$. Then we choose specific subsets - we can take every permutation of i. We do that for each of n+1 elements so we make it a power $n+1$.

$$\left( \sum^{k-1}_{i=0} {{k}\choose{i}}i! \right)^{n+1}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: By the way $[n]$ usually refers to a set of size $n$ that is $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Anyway, the $i!$ shouldn't be there. There's no order for which an element is assigned to the subsets that it belongs to. So the answer comes out to $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}\right)^n=\left(2^k-1\right)^n$

Comment: Not sure what $i!$ is doing here.  There are $2^k$ susbsets of the indices $(1, \cdots, k)$ and you just want to exclude the one subset that covers all of them.  Thus $(2^k-1)$.  And there are $n$ objects in total, so $(2^k-1)^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I just try to explain the argument and the solution given in the comments, as I found it a bit difficult to relate the question and the comments.

We are given $n$ and $k$ and want to count the number of sequences $(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k)$ where each $A_j \subseteq [n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and where $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k \neq \emptyset$.

Any of the sequences we are interested can be represented uniquely as a function $f: [n] \mapsto \Bbb{P}([k])$, where $f$ maps $i \in [n]$ to the set of indices $j$ such that $i \in A_j$. The constraint that $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k \neq \emptyset$ corresponds to the constraint that $f(i) \neq [k]$ for any $i$: i.e., the range of $f$ must comprise proper subsets of $[k]$. $[k]$ has $2^k - 1$ proper subsets and so we have $(2^k-1)^n$ choices for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, one can create such a table:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **$A_1$** | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| **$A_2$** | 1 |  |  |  | 1 |  |
| **$A_3$** | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| **$A_4$** |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |
| **$A_5$** | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| **$A_6$** | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |

which means $A_1 = \{1, 3, 4\}$ etc.

If the intersection of the sets is to be empty, then no column can be full of $1$'s.

For a given column, there are $2^k$ options, but we discard the option with only $1$'s, so we have $2^k-1$.
There are $n$ columns, so the total number of possibilities is  $(2^k-1)^n$.